# Beginning with Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a CMS controlled website and I'm looking for the best solution to

- Have website DNS zone for the website domain Hosted (for faster DNS Lookups)
- Serve Static content (or the entire website) from the cloud

I've hunted for a novice guide but cannot find anything comprehensive, perhaps somebody could shed some light on my problem.

I've tried using the Management console and creating records sets and buckets, but I'm still lost!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Route 53 can handle all of your DNS. Just create your zone with the records you need and then point your domain to the nameservers for that zone (There should be 4 of them)
2. If you want to send your entire website through a CDN, you can set up cloudfront with a custom origin as being your instance. This would require everything to be more or less static, which depending on your situation may or may not be what you want.

If you happen to be using Wordpress look at w3 cache plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry for the long delay in replying! :)